# how to get a variable value that will be changed later

Tags: php, variables

i have this code

```
$number = 1;
echo $number;

for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $number++;
}
```

the output of `echo $number` is `1` not `11`.

How can get the last `$number` value when I called it before it changed?

Comment: My crystal ball suggests that at least one of the \\ is to be substituted by `function` and that you might be interested in http://docs.php.net/language.variables.scope

Answer (score 1):

Once you output something to the browser, it's done. You cannot change it again later. The only way to handle this is to not output the variable until you have found its final value; ie in the example you move the echo statement to the bottom.

It's generally considered a good idea to first run all of your PHP code and determine all your variables and only *then* start outputting things to the browser in order to prevent the kind of problem you have now.

Comment: you mean that I should put the loop inside a function? and run it before call a variable?

Comment: No, I mean that you should never echo a variable whose value might still change. First do all the calculations, THEN you echo it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = 1;
echo 'before increment :'.$number;

for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $number++;
}
echo 'after increment :'.$number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, now you will get expected result:

```
$number = 1;
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $number++;
}

echo $number;
```

Reason, you have put echo $number before the increment, which was logically wrong: